# How to get a &dyn T from a Box<dyn T>

Tags: rust

I am trying to get a `&dyn T` from a `Box<dyn T>`, as in the following example. However, it fails to compile.

```
trait MyTrait {
    
}

struct Foo;
impl MyTrait for Foo {}

fn main() {
    let b: Box<dyn MyTrait> = Box::new(Foo);
    let c: &dyn MyTrait = &b;
}
```

(https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69c72904fbceae5b55470a878a441b7d)

The error message is

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<dyn MyTrait>: MyTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:27
   |
10 |     let c: &dyn MyTrait = &b;
   |                           ^^ the trait `MyTrait` is not implemented for `Box<dyn MyTrait>`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn MyTrait`
```

It is clear that you can get a `&T` from a `Box<T>`. I don't understand why you cant get a `&dyn T` from a `Box<dyn T>`.

Comment: Could be to do with the fact that dyn T is not sized so cannot be represented by a standard pointer. https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/boxed/index.html#memory-layout

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get a `&dyn T` from a `Box<dyn T>`, use `&*`:

```
let c: &dyn MyTrait = &*b;
```

The `*` is used to *deref* the box into its contents (`dyn MyTrait`) and then `&` is used to get it as a reference.

---

This is also the "right" way to get a `&Foo` from a `Box<Foo>`. The reason that `&b` works with concrete types is because the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait allows `&Box<T>` to be *coerced* to `&T`:

> If T implements Deref<Target = U>, and x is a value of type T, then:
>
> - Values of type &T are coerced to values of type &U

The reason it doesn't work for trait objects is that `&dyn MyTrait` *could* be valid for `&Box<...>` and the coercion isn't attempted even if it fails.

Comment: As an alternative to `&*b`, you can use `b.as_ref()`.